# alert with background mask by jquery.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

how is make a alert with background mask(mask is for full page)? (**i don't want use of plugin**)

**Explanation**: After click on a button or link, show an alert with the background mask.

Like demo in here=> http://thrivingkings.com/apprise/

Comment: What's wrong with the plugin you link to, why not use that?

Comment: @Pekka Plugins are high size, In case can with code thinner go to goal

Comment: @Jennifer that's ridiculous. The plugin is three kilobytes big. That's really about as thin as it can get. I recommend you use it.

Comment: @Pekka i not use just of a plugin, there are other plugin, together they have a high volume

Comment: @Jennifer 3 kilobytes more that get loaded only once shouldn't matter. Is your audience using dial-up modems?

Comment: @Pekka no. i have DSL. but I much prefer not to use the plugin

Comment: @Jennifer not really - I guess you'd have to rebuild the functionality that that plugin offers, which is going to be a lot of work, and I still can't really see the point *why*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the demo you have custom built solution with a lot of options. Without using any plugins or custom scripts - you will not be able to customize alert dialog.

very, very simple sample:

```
.alert { width:200px; height:80px; margin:-40px 0 0 -100px; position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%; background:red; text-align:center; }

        $('#btnAlert').click(function () {
            var $alertDiv = $('<div class="alert">This is the alert text.</div>');
            $('body').append($alertDiv);
            $alertDiv.click(function () {
                $(this).fadeOut(100);
            });
            $alertDiv.fadeIn(100);
        });
```

Comment: it is high size. please give me a simple example?

Comment: high size? the plugin you mentioned is VERY small, it's only 3kb in the minified version (probably if you will implement by custom script - it will be bigger)

Comment: please give me a simple example?